# How to download file with new Dropbox API?

Tags: android, api, download, dropbox

Dropbox now have an apsolutely new API, which is absolutely differ from the old one (it's interesting why), but there's no ANY actual examples in the internet, so I've found only some code in their examples. Here is it:

```
   // Download the file.
   try (OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream (file)) {

       mDbxClient.files ()
       .download (metadata.getPathLower (), metadata.getRev ())
       .download (outputStream);

   }
```

I need to download file from remote folder to the local one, so I need to use this path for example:

`.download ("Backups/backup.ab", "/storage/sdcard/Folder/backup.ab")`

I've tried it, but get a error

> IllegalArgumentException: String 'rev' does not match pattern'

Do you know, what it can be, and `metadata.getPathLower ()` and `metadata.getRev ()` methods are using for? I've learned, that `metadata` var gets from the first argv from execute (), but what this functions do?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if if works for android. I have posted the following method just in case someone is looking for a C# .net solution.

```
private async Task Download(DropboxClient dbx, string folder, string file, string localFilePath)
    {
        using (var response = await dbx.Files.DownloadAsync(folder + "/" + file))
        {
            using (var fileStream = File.Create(localFilePath))
            {
                (await response.GetContentAsStreamAsync()).CopyTo(fileStream);
            }
        }
    }
```

Parameter example:

```
file = "YourFileName.pdf";
folder = "/YourDropboxFolderName";
localFilePath = @"C:\Users\YourUserName\YourFileName.pdf";
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Dropbox API v2 Java SDK](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java)'s [`download` method](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v3.0.x/com/dropbox/core/v2/files/DbxUserFilesRequests.html#download-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) takes these two parameters:

- `String path`
- `String rev`

Per the [`download` method documentation](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v3.0.x/com/dropbox/core/v2/files/DbxUserFilesRequests.html#download-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) there, the first is the remote path of the file in Dropbox you want to download, and the second is the identifier for the revision of the file you want. The second parameter is not the local path where you want to save the file, as it appears you're supplying in your code. Instead, you save the file content using the `.download (outputStream);` portion of the sample code you posted, e.g., as also shown in [this sample code](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java/blob/master/examples/android/src/main/java/com/dropbox/core/examples/android/DownloadFileTask.java#L68).

Also, as stated in the documentation, the second parameter is deprecated and should no longer be used. You can just use [the version of the `download` method that only takes the one parameter](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v3.0.x/com/dropbox/core/v2/files/DbxUserFilesRequests.html#download-java.lang.String-). The code for using it is otherwise the same as the sample.

For reference, in the sample, the `metadata` object is an instance of [`FileMetadata`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v3.0.x/com/dropbox/core/v2/files/FileMetadata.html). You can find more information on the [`getPathLower`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v3.0.x/com/dropbox/core/v2/files/FileMetadata.html#getPathLower--) and [`getRev`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v3.0.x/com/dropbox/core/v2/files/FileMetadata.html#getRev--) methods in the documentation as well.

Comment: Okay, but how the path argument must look? I want to download, for example, the `backup.ab` file, which is placed on `Backups` folder at my app single folder (`Apps/AppName` on Dropbox). I'm using separated function for download, not activity, so how can I get the `FileMetadata` from string filepath?

Comment: That file path would be `/backups/backup.ab`. You can get the path from [`FileMetadata.getPathLower`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v3.0.x/com/dropbox/core/v2/files/FileMetadata.html#getPathLower--). You can get the [`FileMetadata`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v3.0.x/com/dropbox/core/v2/files/FileMetadata.html#getPathLower--) itself from a variety of places in the API, e.g., from [`listFolder`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v3.0.x/com/dropbox/core/v2/files/DbxUserFilesRequests.html#listFolder-java.lang.String-).

Comment: I think so too, but documentation says, that it must match pattern `"(/(.|[\\r\\n])*|id:.*)|(rev:[0-9a-f]{9,})|(ns:[0-9]+(/.*)?)"`, so I have `IllegalArgumentException: String 'path' does not match pattern'` error now.

Comment: What `path` value are you supplying? Note that the `"Backups/backup.ab"` from your initial post is invalid. It needs the leading `"/"`.

Comment: ah yes, thanks a lot, I thought that it's simply a key, not a folder, so it's not required a leading slash. But finally, it's so hard to get their API logic, looks like two download () methods is so strange...